# Can't load controller because of routing

Tags: codeigniter, routes, uri

I want when an user types in url.com/username the profilepage will be shown. I set this up in the routes.php file:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "users/profile/$1";
```

But now when I want to call for example the login controller (url.com/login/) I'm also getting redirected to the userpage (url.com/users/profile/login) instead of the logincontroller.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

You must route all your other page before (:any).

```
$route['login'] = "login";
$route['(:any)'] = "users/profile/$1";
```

Comment: Ah thanks, and is there also an easier way? It seems a lot work to do that for each page.

Comment: By using $route['(:any)'], you're stuck having to specifically state which pages you don't want routed. The only way around that would be to do something like $route['users/(:any)']... but that wouldn't fit your need for having url.com/username.

Comment: TerryMatula is right. There is no easy way to do this with $route['(:any)']. You must route all your controller. But if you have more then one method in your controller (for example login/index, login/index2 etc.) use $route['login/(:any)'] = "login/$1";

Comment: you can have a standard part in the string like /site/login, /site/something, /site/other, etc. then you only have to handle site.  this would mean that no one can have a username of 'site'.  this will also allow you add segments later and not worry about people having created users by that name.